# what is Newton-Raphson Square Method's time complexity?

Tags: algorithm

What is the time complexity of the Newton-Raphson square method?

- [Wikipedia: Newton's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method)

Comment: The first two posters beat me to the punch while I was reading the citizendium link. I am curious. Did you Google "newton raphson complexity"? Citizendium was the first link...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From http://en.citizendium.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method#Computational_complexity:

> Using Newton's method as described
>   above, the time complexity of
>   calculating a root of a function f(x)
>   with n-digit precision, provided that
>   a good initial approximation is known,
>   is O((\log n) F(n)) where F(n) is the
>   cost of calculating f(x)/f'(x)\, with
>   n-digit precision.

However, depending on your precision requirements, you can do better:

> If f(x) can be evaluated with variable
>   precision, the algorithm can be
>   improved. Because of the
>   "self-correcting" nature of Newton's
>   method, meaning that it is unaffected
>   by small perturbations once it has
>   reached the stage of quadratic
>   convergence, it is only necessary to
>   use m-digit precision at a step where
>   the approximation has m-digit
>   accuracy. Hence, the first iteration
>   can be performed with a precision
>   twice as high as the accuracy of x_0,
>   the second iteration with a precision
>   four times as high, and so on. If the
>   precision levels are chosen suitably,
>   only the final iteration requires
>   f(x)/f'(x)\, to be evaluated at full
>   n-digit precision. Provided that F(n)
>   grows superlinearly, which is the case
>   in practice, the cost of finding a
>   root is therefore only O(F(n)), with a
>   constant factor close to unity.

Answer (score 4):

This [article](http://en.citizendium.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method#Computational_complexity) gives a relevant approach as to how to consider the method's complexity.

Answer (score 0):

Newton Raphson Method is an algorithm to solve for the roots of a transcendental equation.

formula:
[Newton Raphson Method Formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IoUaA.png)

If an accurate initial approximation is provided to us and the roots of the equation exists then, the complexity of Newton Raphson Method is O(n) and the best case would be Θ(log(n)).

First we apply a first level of Newton’s method to solve f(x) = sin(x) - 3x^2 .
Each iteration of the given equation requires division of slope with actual value.

If we set the precision of the final answer to m digits right from the start,
then convergence at the first level will require log(m) iterations. This means the complexity
of computing a square root will be Θ(m^α * log(m)) if the complexity of multiplication is Θ(m^α),
given that we have shown that the complexity of division is the same as the complexity of multiplication.

the time complexity of m-digit division is Θ(m^α),